# How to turn off the glow effect of enchanted items in Morrowind?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I would like to know if there is a way to stop enchanted items to gloss, shine, glow or whatever word should be used here. This is what I mean:

[image: enchanted robe]

I couldn't come up with a proper keyword, so I didn't find anything on the Internet about it.

Could you please suggest how I can turn off this effect? Maybe there is a smart console hack or a nice plug-in to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mod called [Cool Enchanted Ambience](http://www.nexusmods.com/morrowind/mods/1454/?) which allows you to wear enchanted gear without reconizing it as enchanted.

## Cool Enchanted Gear Ambience Mod

> You see, I very much dislike the bright, glowy enchanted items' effect because (A) It immediately tells you that it's an enchanted item, and I think it'd be cool if it was harder to tell, and (B) it looks stupid. So I went into the editor and set all the magic effects' ambiences to 50 lightness, 0 saturation with a negative effect. This gives them a shine instead of a bright glow. Also, it means you can't tell at a glance what NPC's enchanted items are, even if you know that they're enchanted. And it means having a full set of enchanted Imperial Steel looks really, really cool. ^_^

Appearently some people don't like enchanted armor since it sucks and no one likes glowing enchanted armor [Of course, to show that it's enchanted, it neds to glow, but people can hide it using the mod].

Another mod is called [Subtle Magic Glow Mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/morrowind/mods/1454/?) which allows enchanted items to have a different look too

## Subtle Magic Glow Mod

> Subtle Magic Glow replaces the 'plastic wrap' around in-game magic items (those equipped by characters or on the ground) with less-obtrusive versions. There are three available: A more transparent version of the Bethesda original, one that is faint, but nonmoving, and one that is nonmoving but slowly fades in and out.

The look of enchanted gear now has a different look, kinda faint look.